# How we can cutomize toolbar of react-native-cn-richtext-editor to add button on it

Tags: react-native, rich-text-editor

I am using react-native-cn-richtext-editor now i want to add custom button on the toolbar of editor. So how we can add cutom button on editor toolbar using react-native-cn-richtext-editor. Please provide some example if any one is able to do it or is there any editor that supports to add custom button on it. Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Pooja.

Comment: Please add a code attempt for reviewers/community to assist in the problem. Thanks

Comment: Hi Pooja, I want to get value from react-native-cn-richtext-editor, could you please help to get that, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your own toolbar as below

```js
<CNToolbar
  style={{
    height: 35,
  }}
  iconSetContainerStyle={{
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }}
  size={30}
  iconSet={[
    {
      type: 'tool',
      iconArray: [{
        toolTypeText: 'image',
        iconComponent:
          <Text style={styles.toolbarButton}>
            image
                </Text>
      }]
    },
    {
      type: 'tool',
      iconArray: [{
        toolTypeText: 'bold',
        buttonTypes: 'style',
        iconComponent:
          <Text style={styles.toolbarButton}>
            bold
                </Text>
      }]
    },
    {
      type: 'seperator'
    },
    {
      type: 'tool',
      iconArray: [
        {
          toolTypeText: 'body',
          buttonTypes: 'tag',
          iconComponent:
            <Text style={styles.toolbarButton}>
              body
                    </Text>
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'tool',
      iconArray: [
        {
          toolTypeText: 'ul',
          buttonTypes: 'tag',
          iconComponent:
            <Text style={styles.toolbarButton}>
              ul
                    </Text>
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'tool',
      iconArray: [
        {
          toolTypeText: 'ol',
          buttonTypes: 'tag',
          iconComponent:
            <Text style={styles.toolbarButton}>
              ol
                    </Text>
        }
      ]
    },
  ]}
  selectedTag={this.state.selectedTag}
  selectedStyles={this.state.selectedStyles}
  onStyleKeyPress={this.onStyleKeyPress}
/>
```

for more detail please check [react-native-cn-richtext-editor's GitHub page](https://github.com/imnapo/react-native-cn-richtext-editor#readme)

Comment: So we can add our cutom button las well using about code but how we and add action method on click of that custom button?

Comment: I haven't used this. However, the documentation says you can. Please check https://github.com/imnapo/react-native-cn-richtext-editor#cntoolbar

Comment: You are most welcome. If my answer helps you to resolve your problem you can mark it right or upvote it this helps others too.